# Oracle: fetch list of inserted data in a day without timestamp column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table in `Oracle`

```
name | number | address
```

I do not have a column to note the insert date and time.

I wish to fetch all the data that was inserted 2 days back. Is it possible to do so in oracle using some system tables?

for starters, I tried the following query

```
select sys.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN),SYS_GUID() from EMPLOYEE;
```

but gave me the following error

```
    ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
08181. 00000 -  "specified number is not a valid system change number"
*Cause:    supplied scn was beyond the bounds of a valid scn.
*Action:   use a valid scn.
```

I am not new to Oracle but this is a challenging task that I have come across.
Please let me know if it is possible, if yes then how???

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: The short answer is no, not using SQL to query tables.  The long answer would involve playing with Backups, Flashback Database and Restore Points, then comparing the current state to the previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be achieved by any means of the query.

Another possible solution to compare with DB snapshot on a daily/timely basis. But, for this, you will require DB `sys` access.

Anyone having a better solution please post.